# Find all the $x$ satisfying this equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is from one of past papers:

**Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus 35\mathbb{Z}$,    and $x^{35}\equiv 5 \pmod{35} $. Find all the $x$ satisfying these conditions.**

I find the equation somewhat related to Fermat's little theorem but clearly $5$ and $35$ are not coprime and they do not meet the requirement given. Many thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we temporarily denote $y=x^{35}$, then you can use the following observation:
$$y\equiv5\pmod{35} \iff y\equiv0\pmod{5} \quad\text{and}\quad y\equiv5\pmod{7}.$$
So you need to solve a system of two congruences:
$$x^{35}\equiv0\pmod{5} \quad\text{and}\quad x^{35}\equiv5\pmod{7}.$$
The first one clearly implies that $x\equiv0\pmod{5}$. And the second one allows applying Fermat's Little Theorem. And then, knowing what $x$ is modulo both $5$ and $7$, you can find its unique value modulo $35$.

**UPDATE:** How do we solve the second congruence? First of all, we can exclude all multiples of $7$, which obviously don't satisfy it (think why).  Now, for all $x$ coprime with $7$, since $7$ is a prime number, Fermat's Little Theorem says that $x^6\equiv1\pmod{7}$. Then one way to solve the congruence is to observe that
$$x^{35}=x^{36}x^{-1}=\left(x^6\right)^6x^{-1}\equiv1^6x^{-1}=x^{-1}\pmod{7},$$
so we need to solve $x^{-1}\equiv5\pmod{7}$.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please explain more about the second one to which you suggest to apply Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: @JamieCarr: See the update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Note that it is enough to check the congruence for $0<x<35$. We see that $10^{35}\equiv 5 \bmod 35$ is the only solution. How does this solve the question for all $x\in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: How do you consider the actual answer a "hint"?

Comment: @Arthur This is not yet a full answer. How do we know that this is true? Also, it should be done for all $x\in \Bbb{Z}$. Moreover we need not exclude the case $35\mid x$.

Comment: It's not a full solution. It is, however, the full _answer_.

Comment: I tried to say more clearly what the hint is. Of course, the "result" still is there, but this is perhaps good.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Does the Chinese remainder theorem help? I use the theorem to combine the two results I get and obtain the final result and it states it is only solution.